# Appium - Android - Unable to interrogate elements in certification apks

Tags: android, certificate, appium, android-install-apk, appium-android

I need some help understanding why driver.findElement() or find element APIs of Appium doesn't work in any of the apks from certification builds, but they work in the official released version from the app store.

Just need expert advise before I talk to the dev team since I'm a contractor located in different region than the dev team.

Here is the situation :

1. signed apk (debug version) installed through adb - **Doesn't work**
2. certification build apk installed from app store - **Doesn't work**
3. Official released version from app store - ***WORKS OK !***

I'm fairly new to Android build process. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I tried my best to debug the cerification build apks and figured out none of the driver.findElement APIs work. I would have to use TouchActions as the work around but is a wonky solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of debugging, this doesn't appear to be related to the app signature. 
My app launches the camera with onReady state with an alert message that conceals the elements from Appium which is why the elements are not found. Note that this alert is set up to appear the first time launching the app.

Simplest work around is to dismiss the alert box if present. Solved !